# How to get current inserted auto-incremented primary key in PonyORM?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ponyorm

I am using the following code to get create a new row in the database, using PonyORM:

```
transportTypes = TransportTypes(
    TransportTypeTitle=data['TransportTypeTitle'], 
    Description=data['Description'],
    LatestUpdateDate=datetime.now()
)
```

However, the primary key is still set to `None`. The primary key of the table is auto-incremented, how can I get the generated primary key of the new record?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to explicitly flush the entity, by calling its [`Entity.flush()` method](https://docs.ponyorm.org/api_reference.html#Entity.flush):

> Save the changes made to this object to the database. Usually Pony saves changes automatically and you don’t need to call this method yourself. **One of the use cases when it might be needed is when you want to get the primary key value of a newly created object which has autoincremented primary key before commit.**

*Bold emphasis mine*

For your example, that would be:

```
transportTypes = TransportTypes(
    TransportTypeTitle=data['TransportTypeTitle'], 
    Description=data['Description'],
    LatestUpdateDate=datetime.now()
)
transportTypes.flush()
print(transportTypes.id)
```

Another option would be to explicitly *commit* first. From the [*Saving objects in the database* section](https://docs.ponyorm.org/working_with_entity_instances.html#saving-objects-in-the-database):

> If you need to get the primary key value of a newly created object, you can do `commit()` manually within the `db_session()` in order to get this value[.]
>
> ```
> # [...]
>
> @db_session
> def handler(email):
>     c = Customer(email=email)
>     # c.id is equal to None
>     # because it is not assigned by the database yet
>     commit()
>     # the new object is persisted in the database
>     # c.id has the value now
>     print(c.id)
> ```

So, when using [`db_session`](https://docs.ponyorm.org/api_reference.html#db_session) as a context manager, which commits automatically when the context exits, you could use:

```
with db_session:
    transportTypes = TransportTypes(
        TransportTypeTitle=data['TransportTypeTitle'], 
        Description=data['Description'],
        LatestUpdateDate=datetime.now()
    )

# context has been exited, the session has been committed
# and the identity map has been cleared, so accessing attributes loads
# them fresh from the database
print(transportTypes.id)
```